# 1.Google login error are Google 10: or 12500 errors, and 2.Facebook Login error

Tags: android, facebook

I am facing two errors. one is with Google: after logging in: error with D/Google 10:

- I tried and followed how to solve this error but couldn't solved and find well, and then it is returning back to login page again, showing Google 10:
- I added requestIdToken getString R.string.server_client_idin there but it still doesn't work.

Next is with Facebook: after logging in: returning back to login page;
I logging with Facebook and type Facebook email and password, and then logged in. After logged in, it is nothing go to my website page and refreshing back in the login page without showing any errors.

is there something wrong?

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoginView {

    private TextView tvEmail;
    private TextView tvPassword, link_signUp, link_forgotPassword;
    private Button bLogin;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private Button fb, google;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private SignInButton signInButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        initializeActionBar();
        setTitle("My Account");

        initviews();

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = tvEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = tvPassword.getText().toString();

                new LoginPresenter(ThreadExecutor.getInstance(), MainThreadImpl.getInstance(), LoginActivity.this).validLogin(email, password);
            }
        });

        link_signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

        link_forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Success");
                            String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                            Log.d("mylog", "JSON Result" + jsonresult);

                            new LoginPresenter(ThreadExecutor.getInstance(), MainThreadImpl.getInstance(), LoginActivity.this).validSocialLogin(json.optString("id"), json.optString("name"), json.optString("email"));
                        }
                    }
                });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

                //CustomToast.showToast(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", R.color.colorSuccess);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                CustomToast.showToast(LoginActivity.this, "Login canceled", R.color.colorWarning);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Log.d("FaceBook Response :",exception.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == 200) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
        else {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private void initviews(){
        tvEmail = findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        tvPassword = findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        bLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        link_signUp = findViewById(R.id.link_signUp);
        link_forgotPassword = findViewById(R.id.link_forgotPassword);
        fb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

        fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                loginButton.performClick();
            }
        });

        google = findViewById(R.id.google);
        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        google.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 200);
            }
        });

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 200);
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            //CustomToast.showToast(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", R.color.colorSuccess);

            new LoginPresenter(ThreadExecutor.getInstance(), MainThreadImpl.getInstance(), LoginActivity.this).validSocialLogin(account.getId(), account.getDisplayName(), account.getEmail());

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.d("Google Login", String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
            CustomToast.showToast(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), R.color.colorDanger);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setLoginResponse(AuthResponse authResponse) {
        if (authResponse.getUser() != null){
            UserPrefs userPrefs = new UserPrefs(getApplicationContext());
            userPrefs.setAuthPreferenceObject(authResponse, "auth_response");

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
        else {
            CustomToast.showToast(LoginActivity.this, authResponse.getMessage(), R.color.colorDanger);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showErrorResponse() {
        CustomToast.showToast(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid email or password! Otherwise your email is not verified yet.", R.color.colorDanger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Google 10: or 12500 errors have been fixed/solved by changing server_client_id using Web application.**

I had Google 10:/ 12500 error because of wrong client id with type:
Type: Android application
Client ID:506814367274-xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com

//now, the correct one is
Type: Web application
Client ID:506814367274-xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com

Details:

**First**:

1. Create new project with https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Follow: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
3. Where are you calling from => Android
4. package name, SHA-1 signing certificate
5. to get SHA-1
   (Here with two ways to get SHA-1;

***5.1*** follow `keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v`
(to run this code, go to cmd example my Java directory folders and file is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin` and then replace with your keystore.jks directory is example => `keytool -keystore C:\kkmmshoppings\keystore.jks -v`
and then you will get SHA-1)

***5.2*** the next way is: go to Android Studio -> Gradle on the right corner-> under your `project name->app->Tasks->Android->signingReport->` then you will get SHA-1 with debug.

**6.** put SHA-1 in No.4

**7.**(optional) download credentials.json and you can add it /app folder.

**8. ** go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and choice your project.
you are seeing now in OAuth 2.0 Client IDs.
copy Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in) of Client ID:

**9.** paste it in your string.xml

```
<string name="server_client_id">your copy code, paste it in here</string>
</resources>
```

I hope I could help to solve same errors who are facing on it Google 10: / 12500.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for Facebook Login error:
by updating condition:

```
new LoginPresenter(ThreadExecutor.getInstance(), MainThreadImpl.getInstance(), LoginActivity.this).validSocialLogin(json.optString("id"), json.optString("name"), !json.optString("email").contains("@") ? json.optString("id")+"@facebook.com" : json.optString("email"));
```

I hope, **all my questions with all my answers** could help the one who was facing those kinds of errors.